# Poset map and fibration

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f:P\to Q$ be a poset map between finite posets. 
Then $f$ induces a simplicial map (also denoted by $f$) $f:\Delta(P)\to \Delta(Q)$. 
Are there sufficient non-trivial combinatorial properties for the map $f$ and $P,Q$ to be some kind of fibration, e.g. a Kan fibration when the order complexes are viewed as simplicial sets?

Comment: $\Delta (P)$ is the nerve of $P$ ?

Comment: @Max: Yes, $\Delta(P)$ is the nerve of $P$ (also known as the order complex), considered as a simplicial complex.